# Why these patterns form in captured image while zooming?

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference

[image: zooming of image -gif format]

This is a gif format video that shows zooming of an image of computer LCD screen which i captured using my mobile phone. You can see that some fringes are forming and disppearing and hence some patterns are forming while i zoon in or out. How will you explain this phenomena?

## 1. I could also see same kind of pattern formation in photograph of a mobile screen also

## 2. Try zooming this image ,check wether you can see it [image: use this image to zoom out and zoom in slowly(slowly)].

## 3.when i tried to reduce the image file size to upload it here i could see that reducing file size less than a boundary give away that effect. So i am not sure you will see the effect in above image thats why i used a gif video of zooming

## 4.i should also check wether i get the same effect when trying to zoom original picture using computer( i will update this when done)

If more details needed please ask me.
Whatever ,How is this happening ?

Comment: This is not a question about physics.  It's a question about digital image processing. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: This is basically caused by the pixels from one medium not lining up with the pixels on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are seeing is a form of something called a moire' pattern which is created because as Bill Oertell points out, the spacing between adjacent pixels in the screen does not match that of the camera photographing the screen. You can learn more about moire' patterns on wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

https://xkcd.com/1814/

Apparently this isn't enough text so [here is a real explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moire_pattern)